# Adding Complex Header From One Word Doc to Another

Tags: c#, openxml

I am using the `AddHeaderFromTo` function from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc546917.aspx. The issue is that it's not taking any images or tables that might be found in the header section of the document.  Is there a way to get everything from the header into the other document?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to manually copy them individually based on the type of content your header holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using OpenXMLPowerTools I was able to use the following code to take the headers from one file and insert them into another:

```
var to = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\_Blank_Skeleton.DOCX";
var from = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\Letterheads\StandardLetterhead3.DOCX";
var outDoc = @"C:\Users\dheale\Desktop\Word Docs\test.DOCX";

var sources = new List<Source>
{
    new Source(new WmlDocument(to), false),
    new Source(new WmlDocument(from), true)
};

DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, outDoc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The VBA script below should do it for you.  Run from a Word document.  Modify to suit.

```
Sub editAll()
    Dim Doc
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim docToOpen As FileDialog
    Set docToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    docToOpen.Show
    For i = 1 To docToOpen.SelectedItems.Count
        'Open each document
        Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docToOpen.SelectedItems(i))

        With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
            'insert new headers
            Call editheader
        End With
    Next i
End Sub


Sub editheader()

    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
        ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    With Selection.PageSetup
        .LineNumbering.Active = False
        .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
        .TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .LeftMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .RightMargin = InchesToPoints(1)
        .Gutter = InchesToPoints(0)
        .HeaderDistance = InchesToPoints(0.1)
        .FooterDistance = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .PageWidth = InchesToPoints(8.5)
        .PageHeight = InchesToPoints(11)
        .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
        .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
        .SuppressEndnotes = False
        .MirrorMargins = False
        .TwoPagesOnOne = False
        .BookFoldPrinting = False
        .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
        .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
        .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
    End With
    Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = Not Selection.HeaderFooter. _
        LinkToPrevious
    Selection.HeaderFooter.LinkToPrevious = Not Selection.HeaderFooter. _
        LinkToPrevious
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\rshuell001\Desktop\test\asher.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't run it via VBA Script, It has to be server side in C#.