# Replace the header in a docx with the header image from another docx

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm currently trying to replace the header in a docx with the header image from another docx, I followed the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-replace-the-header-in-a-word-processing-document) from the ms docs, but it seems it is not designed to transfer images from a header from the source document to another.

Here is what is happening to the target docx:

[Target docx result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWkk6.png)

I opened the target docx zip and compared against the source docx and found out there are multiple elements missing in the target docx, such as /media folder and images, header.xml.rels and some details in [Content_types].xml file. When I move this copy/edit this files manually I'm able to see the image correctly.

**So my question is, how to transfer this elements programatically?**

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```cs
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        string filepathFrom = "path";
        string filepathTo = "path";
        AddHeaderFromTo(filepathFrom, filepathTo);
    }

    public static void AddHeaderFromTo(string filepathFrom, string filepathTo)
    {
        // Replace header in target document with header of source document.
        using (WordprocessingDocument 
            wdDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepathTo, true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            
            // Delete the existing header part.
            mainPart.DeleteParts(mainPart.HeaderParts);

            // Create a new header part.
            HeaderPart headerPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
            
            
            // Get Id of the headerPart.
            string rId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);
            
            // Feed target headerPart with source headerPart.
            using (WordprocessingDocument wdDocSource = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepathFrom, true))
            {
                HeaderPart firstHeader = wdDocSource.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.FirstOrDefault();
            
                wdDocSource.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstHeader != null)
                {
                    headerPart.FeedData(firstHeader.GetStream());
                }
            }

            // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference with new Id.
            IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sectPrs = mainPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();
            foreach (var sectPr in sectPrs)
            {
                // Delete existing references to headers.
                sectPr.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();

                //Adding Title Page property
                sectPr.PrependChild(new TitlePage());

                // Create the new header reference node.
                sectPr.AppendChild(new HeaderReference() { Id = rId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First });
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _I followed the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-replace-the-header-in-a-word-processing-document#sample-code) from the ms docs, but it seems it is not designed to transfer images from a header from the source document to another_:  According to the URL that you referenced: _The following code example shows how to replace the header in a word processing document with the header from another word processing document_. It seems that your code above doesn't exactly match the code in the example. Did you try the code exactly as written?

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I did but the results regarding the image are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was revisiting this problem and found something that worked for me in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745157/11213291

This library named OpenXmlPowerTools has a function (DocumentBuilder) that can be used to transfer the headers and footers from a document (Source2.docx) to another (Source1.docx). Heres is the code:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE file in the project root for full license information.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Validation;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;

namespace DocumentBuilderExample
{
    class DocumentBuilderExample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = DateTime.Now;
            var tempDi = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("ExampleOutput-{0:00}-{1:00}-{2:00}-{3:00}{4:00}{5:00}", n.Year - 2000, n.Month, n.Day, n.Hour, n.Minute, n.Second));
            tempDi.Create();

            string source1 = "../../Source1.docx";
            string source2 = "../../Source2.docx";
            List<Source> sources = null;

            // Create new document from 10 paragraphs starting at paragraph 5 of Source1.docx
            sources = new List<Source>()
            {
                new Source(new WmlDocument(source1), false),
                new Source(new WmlDocument(source2), true),
            };
            DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, Path.Combine(tempDi.FullName, "Out1.docx"));

        }
    }
}
```

There is even a video explaining everything: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCShcq8qOg0

Answer (score 1):

I already tried a lot of things and lost a lot of time with images in the header, and what just worked with image in headers for me is start from a template document with the image already of the header, copy that file with a new name and then edit as i needed.

I think that part of the library open xml is not made, there is a related issue opened in their official github since October 2021
https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/issues/1040

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, instead of moving my headers to my headerless file (which is created in a way I can't add the header before), I move the contents of my headerless file to my file with a header. So simple yet I couldn't see.